# How to stop the loop in slider which i use in Tilda

Tags: javascript

1)Hello to everyone. How can istop the jump from the first slide to the last one and back. it must be stoped when the limit of the number of slides is reached.

2)How can i make a pagination button to be disabled with 0.5 opacity in the extreme position (the first slide and the last slide) [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr48E.png).

```
<script>
(function () {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(`.slider`);
    const buttonLeft = document.querySelector(`.slider__btn--left`);
    const buttonRight = document.querySelector(`.slider__btn--right`);
    const dots = document.querySelectorAll(`.dot`);

    let curSlide = 0;
    const maxSlide = slides.length - 1;
    let slideArr = [];

    const dotFill = (slide) => {
        dots.forEach((el, i) => {
            if (i === slide) {
                el.classList.add("cur_dot");
            } else if (el.classList.contains("cur_dot")) {
                el.classList.remove("cur_dot");
            }
        });
    };

    const classSlide = (elementClass) => {
        elementClass.forEach((el) => {
            slideArr.push(document.querySelector(`.tn-elem__${el} .tn-atom`));
        });
    };
    const fillSlide = (slidesArray, link, controls, muted, playsinline) => {
        slidesArray.forEach((el, i) => {
            el.insertAdjacentHTML(
                `beforeend`,
                `<div class="video-container">
                <div class="video-card">
                <video ${muted ? "" : "muted"} ${playsinline ? "playsinline" : ""
                } ${controls ? "controls" : "autoplay"} preload="metadata">
                <source src="${link[i].replace(
                    "https://www.dropbox.com",
                    "https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com"
                )}#t=0.001" type="video/mp4" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = ${muted}">
                </video>
                </div>
                </div>`
            );
        });
    };

    const classArray = ["6273074581691877236257",
        "6273074581691877731323",
        "6273074581691877748465",
        "6273074581691877771834",
        "6273074581691877790410",
        "6273074581691877801530",
        "6273074581691877814586",
        "6273074581691877827282",
        "6273074581691879608980",
        "6273074581691879650426"];

    classSlide(classArray);

    const linksArray = ["https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9bfttgotrymof14gio4if/1.mp4?rlkey=mahxcnu7c5x3twr0khxt3u43h&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k91yehjt2lqc4eo4w6665/2.mp4?rlkey=0x0nepmmupqgkmalvauzui92o&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gd5vbtgssyb0hkih4q7hu/3.mp4?rlkey=yq76364kkwsw2r15x6hus061z&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wrrgsrdtxdxdquf8nlypc/4.mp4?rlkey=03e7cuc1pajwanrj0rj5zu624&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ultat8awgnagbjucu2len/5.mp4?rlkey=pdhjlvyqoo9i9lzmaai2869ha&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2db90pnupmvfr60mtvxw0/6.mp4?rlkey=kjmoggpkfctgqts4mcxdi0wzq&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xtuyvl9hslhpfeqiperij/7.mp4?rlkey=1dz64y3ugci2hcqhy5ttay0wz&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2pptx7qzv9mfwgjil9rxe/8.mp4?rlkey=dgl20izazspbul2q9foxkqlkf&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/clxwm1cx6duz1oc7lqjz1/9.mp4?rlkey=murp4lqr6wls3m44m8fy8da9d&dl=0",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/t24r7b0a32f3ug9k4r07m/10.mp4?rlkey=fqzsg2let5arqthrlhy920xhf&dl=0"];


      fillSlide(
        slideArr,
        linksArray,
        "controls",
        "unmuted",
        "playsinline"
    );

    const initCondition = () => {
        goToSlide(0);
        dotFill(0);
    };

       const toNextSlide = () => {
        if(curSlide === maxSlide){ 
            buttonRight.classList.add("slider__btn--right--disabled");
            return;
        }
        if(curSlide <= 0){ 
            buttonRight.classList.remove("slider__btn--right--disabled");
        } 
        curSlide++;
        goToSlide(curSlide);
        dotFill(curSlide);
    };
    const toPrevSlide = () => {
        if(curSlide <= 0){ 
            buttonLeft.classList.add("slider__btn--left--disabled");
            return;
        }
        if (curSlide === maxSlide) {
            buttonLeft.classList.remove("slider__btn--left--disabled");
         }
        curSlide--;
        goToSlide(curSlide);
        dotFill(curSlide);
    };
    buttonRight.addEventListener(`click`, toNextSlide);
    buttonLeft.addEventListener(`click`, toPrevSlide);
    document.addEventListener(`keydown`, (e) => {
        e.key === `ArrowRight` && toNextSlide();
        e.key === `ArrowLeft` && toPrevSlide();
    });
    dots.forEach((el, i) =>
        el.addEventListener("click", () => {
            dotFill(i);
            goToSlide(i);
        })
    );
    initCondition();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop when the limit of the number of slides is reached, make changes to the toNextSlide and toPrevSlide function.

```
const toNextSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide === maxSlide) return;
    curSlide++;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
const toPrevSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide <= 0) return;
    curSlide--;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
```

In order to disable the the NEXT and PREVIUOS buttons on extreme positions you need to make following modification to the above version of the code

```
const toNextSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide === maxSlide){ 
     buttonRight.disabled = true;
     return;
    }
    if(curSlide <= 0){ 
     buttonLeft.disabled = false;
    } 
    curSlide++;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
const toPrevSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide <= 0){ 
     buttonLeft.disabled = true;
     return;
    }
    if (curSlide === maxSlide) {
        buttonRight.disabled = false;
     }
    curSlide--;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
```

In order to add style to disabled button use CSS. Suppose the CSS class named disabled

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .65;
}
```

Make the following changes to the above version of the code

```
const toNextSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide === maxSlide){ 
     buttonRight.classList.add("disabled");
     return;
    }
    if(curSlide <= 0){ 
     buttonLeft.classList.remove("disabled");
    } 
    curSlide++;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
const toPrevSlide = () => {
    if(curSlide <= 0){ 
     buttonLeft.classList.add("disabled");
     return;
    }
    if (curSlide === maxSlide) {
        buttonRight.classList.remove("disabled");
     }
    curSlide--;
    goToSlide(curSlide);
    dotFill(curSlide);
};
```

Comment: There is an error in console with the second part where we need to disable the the NEXT and PREVIUOS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (at (index):290:13). 
its in part (curSlide === maxSlide) && buttonRight.disabled = false;
the browser doesnt like these brackets.

Comment: The first part with stopping the loop is working wonderfull, thank you very much

Comment: As i can understand, I need add class for the buttons .slider__btn--left and slider__btn--right in disabled state and then style it in CSS. but i cant undartand, how to do it in my code, help, please

Comment: I've edited the answer, try now

Comment: its ready, but how can i make opacity 0.5 in disabled state for buttons?
i tried to add element.classList.add("") and element.classlist.remove("") in your Conditional Constructs and it works wrong

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate the use of CSS class in the above code snippet.If it works for you, make sure to endorse the answer.

Comment: I wrote exactly the same code that you wrote, it doesn't work correctly. The "buttonLeft" button does not have a new class in the extreme position, but only if you click on it again from this extreme position. And the class disappears as wrong. I'll try to explain the mechanics:

Comment: I'm on the first slide, by default the "buttonLeft" button should be inactive, it should have the "disabled" class. But it is not there and it is active until I click it again, then the "disabled" class appears. but after switching to the second slide, the 'disabled' class does not disappear until I click on the 'buttonLeft' button again. Then the browser sees that the button is no longer in the extreme position and removes the "disabled" class

Comment: The same situation is with the button "buttonRight". And if i use " pointer-events: none;" in CSS for class "disabled', both of buttons are blocked after goint throught the whole slider + 1 click extra. i changed the code, look at it in the beggining

Comment: I've seen your modified code. There is a difference, in the toNextSlide you are targeting the classList of buttonRight in both the if blocks. Similarly in  toPrevSlide you have used buttonLeft in both if block. Please compare it with mine. Moreover, in order to disable PREVIOUS button by default, please add the disabled class in the HTML file. This would work.